# How to show interpreted HTML in title attribute of a div, taken from Angular string variable?

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular variable myAngularVariable="`some<br>HTML text`" and a div

```
<div [innerHTML]="myAngularVariable" title="{{myAngularVariable}}"></div>
```

This way, inside the div I get the HTML of the variable interpreted, i.e. inside the div the result shown is

```
some
HTML text
```

but when i hover to show the title tooltip I get "`some<br>HTML text`".

There is a way to show on hover the HTML text interpreted?

Comment: it is not supported by the HTML, so no way to make it work without making a separate "title" directive which will render a popup with html supported

Answer (score -1):

If you must put a newline in `title` then replace the HTML `<br>` with new line `\n`.

```
<div [innerHTML]="myAngularVariable" title="{{myAngularVariable.replace('<br>','\n')}}"></div>
```

Comment: tnx, but it is a general problem with HTML, non only with br

Comment: Plenty of solutions if you search, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp Alternatively, you could use a library component, e.g. Angular Material or ngx-bootstrap. Both of these have tooltip component with HTML support.